# Run-Time error '5' : invalid argument when running second = Dir

Tags: vba

I am having an issue with a code, I know it is not not perfect and very snappy but I am still learning the whole vba thing. the issue i am having is when I loop and get to the second `=dir`

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim StrFolder As Variant
    Dim StrFile As String




    StrFolder = "C:\temp\output\"
    StrFile = Dir("C:\temp\output\")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=StrFolder & StrFile)
        strSearch = "2675"

    Set ws = Worksheets("TestCases")


    With ws
        Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

         If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
            Set bcell = aCell

                Columns("E:E").Insert
            aCell.Offset(0, 2) = "FD/WagesAmt"
            strSearch = Dir
    End If
    End With

            strSearch = "2017"
                Set ws = Worksheets("TestCases")
                With ws
                Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                Set bcell = aCell

                aCell.Offset(0, 2) = "FD/Amt"
                aCell.Offset(5, 2) = "FD/Amt"
                strSearch = Dir

        End If
    End With
     strSearch = "2078"
                Set ws = Worksheets("TestCases")

                With ws
                Set aCell = .Columns(3).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

                If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
                Set bcell = aCell
                aCell.Offset(0, 2) = "FD/mt"
                aCell.Offset(5, 2) = "FD/mt"
                    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
                    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                strSearch = Dir

        End If
     StrFile = Dir

    End With


        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

when it finish the first loop and goes to the next then `strSearch = Dir` is coming back with the run time error and I am not sure why this is. any help is extremely appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you using both `strFile` and `strSearch` with `Dir`?

Comment: because I am just learning and don't know what else to do :(

Comment: Get rid of all the lines that say `strSearch = Dir`. And the duplicate `strFile = Dir`.

Comment: if I do that then the loop never ends and also keeps on using the same file it does't go to the next file.

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question with the updated code you are using.

Comment: @BigBen what I ended up doing was to remove all but the last `StrFile = Dir` from the code and now it is running like I want it to. Thank you